# How using MbUnit can I set a StaticTestFactory to be parallelized?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mbunit

I have a large number of test set-up through a StaticTestFactory, but when I put any form of paralleization on it then it doesn't seem to effect it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not supported yet. It was [expected to be available](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=475) in [Gallio/MbUnit](http://gallio.org) v3.2 but should finally be implemented v3.3.